# Flexbox Responsive Navigation bar - justify-content : flex-end not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigationbar

I'm learning Flex-box now. I'm trying to make a navigation bar using flex box, but there is a problem. I want my `nav-bar-flex` class go to right side, so I used `justify-content: flex-end` to my class but it's not working.
I want only `nav-bar-flex` class to go to the right side and not the brand-name class.
Here is my code:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.header {
 background: gray;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}
/*
.main-container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
*/
.main-head {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

.link {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 width: 8em;
}
.nav-bar-flex{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.brand-name {
 width: 15em;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.link:hover{
 background: black;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
   <div class="main-container main-head">
   <div class="brand">
    <a class="brand-name link" href="index.html">Saurabh <span class="highlite">Vishwakarma</span></a>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-bar">
    <nav class="nav-bar-flex">
     <a class="link" href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a class="link" href="services.html">Services</a>
     <a class="link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a class="link" href="about.html">About</a> 
    </nav>
   </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: .main-head {justify-content: space-between}

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin-left: auto` to `nav-bar` element to *pull* the navigation to the right - see demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}


/*
.main-container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
*/

.main-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 8em;
}

.nav-bar-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.brand-name {
  width: 15em;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.link:hover {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.nav-bar {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="main-container main-head">
    <div class="brand">
      <a class="brand-name link" href="index.html">Saurabh <span class="highlite">Vishwakarma</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <nav class="nav-bar-flex">
        <a class="link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a class="link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <a class="link" href="about.html">About</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```